# Find the secret phrase in this encrypted image (part 3)

Tags: visual, cipher, lateral-thinking, steganography

Welcome to part 3 of Quark's quest to make an image puzzle that isn't solved in under an hour. Like the last one, this will be much more difficult than the last.

In the below encrypted message, there are stages that lead from one to the next. There are two main words to discover, one at the ~75% completion mark, and one at the finish line. Put them together and you'll have a phrase related to computing.

What is that phrase?

[image]

Hints definitely aren't needed to solve this but if it goes past a day or two I'll start giving hints. However, if this is solved under two hours then I'll admit that I underestimate this puzzling community and I'll be forced use drastic measures for part 4.

Note: The "ovals" in the picture are different sizes, ignore this because I made this sloppily in Paint. This was originally supposed to make smart puzzlers go "well he probably doesn't want us measuring their radii/center position so I'll ignore it" but I realize it's better to explicitly state it.

Note 2: There is no extra information in this puzzle other than the size thing mentioned above. I realized there is a phrase related to computing that is discovered around the 40% completion mark but this is not related to the answer and is just a hint on how to progress further.

Comment: The "circles" have different sizes. Is this intentional?

Comment: @leoll2 I literally edited the post to include this note the same second you posted that comment lol.

Comment: Just saw this... I guess I have ten minutes to beat you to an hour =P

Comment: @2012rcampion I made this one a lot tougher than the last one, good luck solving it in 10 minutes xD

Comment: Just noticed the trick... you're lucky I didn't immediately reach for `Histogram` this time!

Comment: Looking at @2012rcampion answer, I'd suggest to add the tag steganography if you think it's appropriate.

Comment: @leoll2 I added it, although I was thinking it'd be better to leave it out and make it a hint people discover by looking at parts 1 and 2.

Comment: If you didn't want us to look at the circle positions you should have made them the same size... Instead of Paint try something like Inkscape or the GIMP, both free software.

Comment: @2012rcampion I actually use both of those software (vector graphics ftw), I purposely made the circles varying sizes at first to be a false hint then decided against it. It'd actually be easier to just copy paste them.

Comment: @2012rcampion plus it looks better this way IMO

Comment: Do we need a particular software to decrypt the data block?  So far all of my statistical analysis indicate it's totally random (p < .05).

Comment: @2012rcampion you'll need a resource online but you don't have to download anything. I suppose the last step is a bit unfair if you haven't seen it before but I've seen this resource (found on the internet) used multiple times for this type of puzzle.

Comment: That's what I figured: I just wanted to double-check before I spend an hour chasing down which one you used.  (And I don't think it's unfair.)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

(No spoiler tags because they're messing with the line breaks...)

First we do a trivial reshaping of the image to un-distort it:

```
img = Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/fIAv4.png"]
rectified = Image[ArrayReshape[ImageData[img, Automatic], {400, 399, 3}], "Byte"]
```

[image]

After noticing that the black pixels are not all exactly black, I
extracted the lowest bit from each pixel:

```
bitImg = Image[Mod[ImageData[rectified, Automatic], 2], "Bit"]
```

[image]

`ZBEFR PBQR` is `MORSE CODE` rot13'd.  This suggests that part of the puzzle will be decoded using Morse code.  After extensive randomness testing on the data burst at the top of the image, I switched to analyzing the dots.

First I played around with separating the color channels, since the pure/saturated primary colors suggested per-channel binary data.  This lead nowhere.

Finally I pulled up the [Morse code Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Morse_code), and immediately noticed that `H` is encoded as four dots.  Where had I seen those before?  The red dots at the top of the image.  The two letters I know, `T` (`-`) and `E` (`.`) are both single dots: corresponding to the dots on either side of the four red ones.  Put it all together and you get `THE`!  I realized that the colors were a Morse code substitution cipher with the following mapping:

```
RED   => DOT (·)
BLUE  => DASH (-)
BLACK => LETTER SPACE (/)
GREEN => WORD SPACE ( )
```

This allows us to decode the dots as:

```
 bkrrrrkrgrbbrkrbkrrrkrrrgrrkrrrgrkbbkbrrrkrkbrrkbrrkrkbrr
 -/..../. .--./.-/.../... ../... ./--/-..././-../-.././-..
  T  H  E    P  A  S  S    I  S   E  M  B  E  D  D  E  D
```

Entering `embedded` as the password into a [suitable online decrypter](http://www.mobilefish.com/services/steganography/steganography.php), we obtain the following image file (`chip.png`):

[image]

Therefore the answer is **EMBEDDED CHIPS**.

Comment: Nice progress so far, you probably don't need me to say it but you're definitely on the right track.

Comment: Good job you got the whole thing, I think you can safely say you're a puzzles guy =)

Comment: I kind of expected the data burst at the top of the bit-slice image to be raw bytes (I've done that before to embed *Mathematica* code into an image), so I spent *way* too long trying to figure out what encoding you were using... It took me an hour to realize that you probably just used an online encrypter like a normal person =)

Comment: Wow! Super-complex puzzle, @Quark - so great work 2012rcampion for unravelling all the layers!

Comment: Which picture did you decrypt with the password 'embedded' to get the final answer?

Comment: @BaileyM I just tested, it works on all three images.  The first and second both work because (I assume) it ingests the bits in reading order (left-to-right then top-to-bottom), and moving pixels from the end of one row to the beginning of the next doesn't change that order.  The last one works because if the LSB was originally `0`, the new pixel value will be `0x00` (LSB = `0`), and if it was one, the new value is `0xFF` (LSB = `1`): essentially, my transformation left the lowest bit-plane unchanged.

Answer (score 6):

From 2012rcampion's answer, we get "morse code".
From this, we can think there's a message in morse hidden in the image;
Morse code needs four symbols: (-), (.), ( ), (/)
In the picture, the ovals come in four colors, so maybe each color stands for one symbol.
Green is the least frequent so it's the word separator, /;
the letter separator can only be black, since red and blue can come in pairs;
red has to be the dot, since the second letter, rrrr, doesn't make sense as dashes (while as dots, it's "h").

recap:
(-) blue
(.) red
( ) black
(/) green

Substituting, we obtain
- .... . / .--. .- ... ... / .. ... / . -- -... . -.. -.. . -..
In morse, it gives:
THE PASS IS EMBEDDED

Comment: 75% finished, now for the final stretch. This last part may require research on the topic of one of the tags.

Comment: Wow, I wish I had scrolled down before trying to work that out myself... I'm a software guy, not a puzzles guy =)

Comment: Conversely, I'm a puzzles guy and not a software guy. I wouldn't have been able to do anything without your answer, nor I have any idea on how to proceed from this point. Hope you can deal the final blow!

Comment: oh wait you did, never mind. congrats!